# Dynamically specify Model in Laravel controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using an abstract controller class that is extended by each individual model controller in my project.

At present, each model controller sets the class of the model in the constructor, and this is used by the abstract to load the appropriate object.

So to take a simple example, my abstract has

```
public function show($id){
    $object = $this->model::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize('view', $object);
    return view($this->view_dir.'.show',$object);
}
```

and my `Referee` class extends it, with a constructor that includes

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->model = 'App\Referee';
    $this->view_dir = 'referees'
}
```

This is working fine, but I would prefer to switch to using authorisation middleware rather than having to remember to manually authorise each action within the controller method.

As I understand it, in order to do so I need to typehint the `show` method with the model, but this is only available as a property of the abstract (and I gather it is not possible to have a dynamic typehint).

Is there another way of binding the model to the controller? I suppose ideally in the constructor of the child class.

Answer (score 0):

Typehinting the model on the controller methods is for `Route model binding`, not authorization

Route model Binding is when you write a route like

```
Route::get('books/{book}', 'BooksController@show');
```

and your controller method will be

```
public function show(Book $book)
{
    // here $book is already the model instance, not the id. It throws 404 automatically if can't find the book by the primary key
}
```

When you saw this on documentation

```
$this->authorize('update', $post);
```

It's because you're checking authorization for the Post instance (the record on the DB, not the model)

To authorize actions on a Resource (the model, not the record on DB) you need do it this way:

```
$this->authorize('create', Post::class);
```

Comment: I understand all that, but I'm saying that I'd prefer to implement authorisation on the middleware of the controller method rather than by calling the authorize method on the model (as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-middleware).

I understand how to do what you're describing as the conventional way to acheive this, but my `show` method is on the abstract class - it will be called by all my models so I can't explicitly declare the type of `$book` in your example. `$book` needs to vary depending on which class is extending the abstract.

Comment: Use authorize in controller constructor with inheritance